# MySQL: difficulty understanding GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have difficulty understanding the correct use of the GROUP by clause in MySQL. It is used in conjunction with aggregate functions. The pattern is:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... column_n, aggregate_function (expression)
   FROM tables
GROUP BY column1, column2, ... column_n;
```

But what I do not understand is whether I have to list, after GROUP BY, *all* columns I did not perform an aggregate function on or not ... Is this the simple rule or did I misunderstand something? Thanks..

Comment: Can you have an actual example?

Comment: No, because what I want to know is if the rule is really that simple or if I am just not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you can but you don't have to.

A query like the following would be illegal in standerd SQL but legal in MySQL:

```
SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
WHERE o.custid = c.custid
GROUP BY o.custid;
```

but then the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Check this link for referemce: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

you don't *need* to do this in **Mysql**, but you will get unpredictable results for the non grouped / non aggregated columns.

As stated in mysql doc :

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they
>   are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

But I would really suggest to list them all, as it's ANSI, mandatory int most dbms, and will give you predictable results.

**Unpredictable example**

Imagine a table with

```
id, code, name
```

with values

```
1, 2, 'a';
2, 2, 'b';
```

if you make

```
select code, name, count(*)
group by code;
```

You  will have only one line returned, but could have either 'a' or 'b' as returned value for name.

Comment: unpredictable results: That's what I've noticed. My queries simply don't work anymore if I spare the GROUP BY. But what is the rationale behind this all?

Answer (score 0):

If you have database with many product_id

For example you have product table and orders table. You just want to get total products in order. Then you use `GROUP BY product_id`. And you will get only with unique id.

Read this to understand more about `GROUP BY`

[Group BY SQL](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlgroupby.php)